# ¿Cual es la sintaxis correcta de input y label en un fomurlario?

Tags: html, css, entrada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
creo que la pregunta es muy basica pero, estoy aprendiendo y he encontrado la sintaxis de input y label de las dos maneras

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Las dos maneras sirven por igual, pero si tienes algún estilo que afecte al label, no afectará a los dos puntos, así que deberías colocarlo dentro de la etiqueta.

Comment: muchas gracias... de gran ayuda recién empiezo en esto

Answer (score 2):

La primera forma está bien, pero no recomiendo de ningún modo la segunda forma, incluso llegaría a ser de esa forma pero si hay elemento que los envuelve, así:

```
<div class="input-text-group">
  <label for="foo0">Label</label> : 
  <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Porque los *dos puntos* (:) podrían heredar los estilos por defecto del padre contenedor e incluso podrían omitirse y crearse usando pseudo-elementos, pero no lo veo como una versión óptima, ya que es un uso visual más que de estructuración de datos, que al fin y al cabo para eso es **`html`**.

No hay mucho consenso del tema, lo puedes hacer dependiendo de la necesidad, por ejemplo mis recomendados serían:

### Label que envuelve el input

Permite controlar dar estilos al texto del label y al input por separado, aunque el input heredará los estilos del label.

```
<label for="foo1">
  Label:
  <input type="test" id="foo1"/>
</label>
```

### Label separado del input

Permite controlar dar estilos al texto del label y al input por separado, pero el input **no heredará** los estilos del label.

```
<label for="foo2">
  Label: 
</label>
<input type="test" id="foo2"/>
```

### Label separado del input y este último anidado

Permite darle estilos al input avanzados, como pseudo-elementos con iconos, así como acomodarlos a una grilla de tamaños. Este es el preferido de los frameworks la mayoría de veces.

```
<label for="foo3">
  Label: 
</label>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="test" id="foo3"/>
</div>
```

Este es el que usa **bootstrap** por dar otro ejemplo:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="foo4">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo4">
</div>
```

Y este el de google con **material design**:

```
<div class="mdc-text-field">
  <input type="text" id="foo6">
  <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="foo6">Hint text</label>
  <span class="mdc-line-ripple"></span>
</div>
```

El ultimo añade una línea de estado, que se puede animar vía css con los estados del input, pero yo prescindiría de ella y usaría pseudos para lograr el mismo efecto.

Yo en muchas ocasiones, he decidido mezclarlos en una versión muy similar a los dos, pero con la posibilidad de poder controlar el label mediante estados css del input, así.

```
<div class="grupo-question">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo7">
  <label for="foo7">Name:</label>
</div>
```

Y acomodo el orden de los elementos usando `flexbox` y `order`, así:

```css
.grupo-question{
  display: flex;
}
.grupo-question .form-label{
  order: 1;
}

.grupo-question .form-label::after{
  content: ':';
  margin-left: -0.2em;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
.grupo-question .form-control{
  order: 2;
}

.grupo-question .form-control:focus ~ .form-label{
  color: blue;
  order: 2;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.grupo-question .form-control:hover ~ .form-label{
  color: red;
}

.grupo-question .form-control:active ~ .form-label{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grupo-question">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="foo7">
      <label for="foo7" class="form-label">Label </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la W3C[Using label elements...](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html)

```
<label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
<input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" />
```

Lo fundamental es que **for** concuerde con **id** en la practica esto es utilizado por sistemas de asistencia como los lectores de pantalla.

Pero en caso de que necesites omitir **label** puedes utilizar **aria-label** para que los lectores de pantalla puedan leer de que trata ese **input**

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" aria-label="Nombre">
```